# Display number of colour swatch based on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my product list template page, I’ve got colour swatches that show available colours for a product. On **mobile** I want to only **display the first 2**, and then provide a “more available” button which takes you through to the specific product page. On **desktop** I want to **display the first 4**, and then provide a “more available” button which also takes you through to the product page.

I can show and hide the colours available on either viewport (with css), however how would I do the variable logic to work out when to provide the “more available” button on desktop and mobile?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!— Product —>
<div class=“product”>
 <div class=“colour-swatches”>
  <ul>
    <li class=“swatch">Red</li>
    <l class=“swatch"i>Blue</li>
    <li class=“swatch">Green</li>
    <li class=“swatch">Orange</li>
    <li class=“swatch">Yellow</li>
    <li class=“swatch">Black</li>
    <li class=“swatch">Lime</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
Li.swatch {

  &:nth-child(-n+2) {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
  }

  @media (min-width: 600px) {

      &:nth-child(-n+3) {
          display: block !important;
          visibility: visible !important;
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all available colors contained within the list, right? (even the ones that aren't visible). If so, you can just count the total number of colors that are available, and the number of colors you're currently displaying. If all available colors are being displayed, then you don't show the more available link, if not, then you show it.

You can use jQuery's `:visible` selector to find out how many of the colors in the list are currently visible (on the current viewport):

http://jsfiddle.net/cms8s720/

```js
var all = $('ul li').length,
    visible = $('ul li:visible').length;

if(all - visible > 0) {
    $('#avail').html( (all - visible) + ' more colors available');
}
```

```css
/* Simplified this for testing. This should work with your CSS */
/* Feel free to experiment with the nth-child value in here */

li:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
 <div class="colour-swatches">
  <ul>
    <li class="swatch">Red</li>
    <li class="swatch">Blue</li>
    <li class="swatch">Green</li>
    <li class="swatch">Orange</li>
    <li class="swatch">Yellow</li>
    <li class="swatch">Black</li>
    <li class="swatch">Lime</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
</div>
<span id="avail"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily in jQuery. You would need to do an if statement based on the length of the color swatch list. As you are doing this conditionally for two different sizes, I suggest the following:

First make a function and within it have the following

```
if ($(window).width() <= MOBILESIZEUSED) {    

    if ($("colour-swatches > ul").length > 2){
        ...code to show more available...
    }
} else {
    if ($("colour-swatches > ul").length > 4){
        ...code to show more available...
    }
}
```

Then you will need to have the following code:

```
$(window).resize(functionNameHere);
functionNameHere();
```

This will mean it runs on resize and runs initially. This should work for you. Also you have an incorrect li tag in your code ^^.